# Impossible to import a 13Gb database on a dedicated server

Tags: mysql, database, import, server

I have a problem importing a 13Gb database on my server with the following configuration:

```
CPU:    Intel Atom C2350 - 1.7 GHz - 2 core(s)
RAM:    4GB - DDR3
Hard Drive(s):  1x 128GB (SSD SATA)
```

After following many mysql configurations on stackoverflow, I have reduced all the values in the my.cnf configuration file:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=""
key_buffer_size = 50M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 100M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 2
innodb_log_file_size = 50M
innodb_write_io_threads = 2
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
sort_buffer_size = 50M
read_buffer_size = 50M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 50M
join_buffer_size = 50M
max_connections = 50M
wait_timeout = 600
max_allowed_packet = 64M
```

However the server still runs out of memory. Current swap is 1Gb I have tried increasing it to 7Gb, but that didn't do much.

So to summarize when I run the import of the dump file it works for some time and then the process gets killed because it runs out of memory. What elements do I need to change/add in my.cnf file for it to continue the process ? I don't mind if it takes 3, 4 days to complete.

Here is the error message:

```
Out of memory (Needed 2098545784 bytes)
mysql: Out of memory (Needed 2601694880 bytes)
```

Here are the logs of memory usage just before the process got killed:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3942        3763         108           0          70          22
Swap:          1048        1037          11

  PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME
16944 91.6 90.1 4206248 3638948 pts/0 R    14:00   6:01
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the error message

Comment: @BerndBuffen I updated the question with additional information

Comment: is the sql file stored on the server ? pls post also the cmd to import this file

Comment: Yes, it is stored on the server, here is the command that I run "nohup mysql -u root --password='mypassword' --binary-mode -o -D db_name < dumpfile.sql &"

Comment: you can also split the file into files per table like https://gist.github.com/jasny/1608062 and import each one separate.

Comment: Unfortunately one of tables is more than 9Gb in size. I have tried multiple tools for splitting the file but they do not work as expected or do not work at all.

Comment: if you can split the sql file to file per table then you can split the 9GB file with linux split tool into small files with n lines. with a small bash script you can add the "INSERT INTO...." at the top of each file and ale a ); at th end

Comment: sorry, can you creat the SQL file again. then you can save it in smaller INSERTS by using the --quick optin

Comment: What were the settings when the `mysqldump` was run?  I am worried that one of the `INSERTs` is 2GB long.

Comment: Do you have any `LONGTEXT` or `LONGBLOB` columns?  What is the biggest such cell?

Comment: You have a bigger problem than can be solved with one question/one answer on this site.  View profile and get in touch.

Comment: I have managed to deal with the problem by manually separating the SQL file. The editor I used is EmEditor that opened the file without any issues.